# Sql Subquery result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables, A, B,C

- Table A,Columns: latlong, name
- Table B, columns : code, name
- Table C, Columns : latlong, code

I want to update table A,column Name with the values from Table B, Column Name, something like:

```
update A set A.name = 
(select b.name 
 from B where code = c.code) 
where a.latlong = c.latlong
```

Note that all the columns are not related.

Would appreciate the right direction to go about it.

Have tried Sub queries with inner joins, but no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned in your question the following:

> I want to update table A,column Name with the values from Table B, Column Name

But what I can see from your query is that actually , you need only those values of the column `Name` of table `B` which has same value of `code` as in table `C`, and that your `latlong` in `A` should be the same as `latlong` in `C`, if I'm not mistaken.

Based on that, I can say you need an SQL **JOIN** operation for Tables `B` and `C` with table `A`. Something like this:

```
UPDATE A SET A.name = B.Name
FROM A
JOIN C
ON C.latlong = A.latlong
JOIN B
ON B.code = C.code
```

No need to create a **SUBQUERY**

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an `update` using `join`:

```
update a
    set name = b.name
    from a join
         c
         on c.latlong = a.latlong join
         b
         on b.code = c.code;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try update with INNER JOIN

```
update A set 
    A.name = B.name
FROM A
INNER JOIN C on C.latlong = A.latlong
INNER JOIN B on B.code = C.code
```

Answer (score 0):

Last condition is missing where Table A.Latlong = C.Latlong to pick up the correct code!